# Htaccess only for friendly urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i rewrite htaccess only for friendly urls?
I have

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)?$ show_a_product.php?product_id=$1    [NC,L]
```

I want redirect **ONLY** for urls like `/products/1` but its working also for `/show_a_product.php?product_id=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another rule to block `/show_a_product.php?product_id=1` URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /show_a_product\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/?$ show_a_product.php?product_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: but it still working when user type something like `show_a_product.php` and in my opinion this should return 404 page, not forbidden page.